# LibraryLink: is WolframLibraryData libData persistent?

Tags: librarylink

I am writing some C++ code that I want to call both through LibraryLink and independently from Mathematica.  Thus it must be compatible with LibraryLink but not depend on it.

When calling it from Mathematica, I want to make it abortable.

All LibraryLink functions take an argument `WolframLibraryData libData` (this is really a pointer).  [`AbortQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/LibraryLink/ref/callbacks/AbortQ.html) is called through it.

**Question:**  Is it safe to cache the value of `libData` in a global variable, never change it after `WolframLibrary_initialize`, and use this global variable for calling all LibraryLink functions?

To make the question clearer, this is the layout of my code:

```cpp
WolframLibraryData libData; // global variable

EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT int WolframLibrary_initialize(WolframLibraryData iLibData) {
    libData = iLibData;
    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}

class MyClass 
{
public:
    void simulate() {
        for (...) { // long loop
            ...
#ifdef WolframLibraryVersion  // use the global libData here:
            if (libData->AbortQ) { /* abort computation */ }
#endif
        }
    }
}
```

[Cross posted to Wolfram Community.](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/295322?p_p_auth=9piKfAzz)

Comment: You have code in `WolframLibrary_initialize`; when is the code actually run?  When I call up multiple functions with `LibraryFunctionLoad`, I find that the code in `WolframLibrary_initialize` is never really called.

Comment: @QuantumDot I am travelling now, so I am answering from memory. It should run *once* when the library is first loaded.  You do not need to use `LibraryLoad` to load it.  In fact as I remember doing so had harmful effects (problems unloading?).  `LibraryLoad` is only for loading dependencies.  Instead use `LibraryFunctionLoad` only, as usual. The first time you load a function from the library, the initialization should run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In several projects, I saved the value of `libData` at library initialization, and used the saved value throughout the lifetime of the library.

So far I have not encountered any problems. Of course that does not mean that there are none.